# How to override a function

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to disable two (annoying) features of CKEditor 4:

1. It writes image width and heights as style attributes on the element (rather than leaving them as width="" height=""), thus messing up liquid layouts.
2. Re-ordering attributes in alphabetical order, thus making them harder to edit.

According to this answer https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Attribute-Sort-Order, the idea is to disable the `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.prototype.writeHtml` function. However, I can't figure out how to do so.

I've tried setting `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.prototype.writeHtml = false;` and various iterations of `disabled` but just get errors.

I also tried to edit the actual function in ckedit.js, as follows.

For this function,

```
var sortAttribs = function( a, b ) {
    a = a[ 0 ];
    b = b[ 0 ];
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I changed it to return

`return 0;`

and this did the trick for sorting the attributes. But it seems far from ideal.

It seems the 2 things I am trying to remove are contained within that function in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/core/htmlparser/element.js#L114

How to override it?

TIA.

Comment: replace it with another function that does what you want. Getting rid of it won't give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B. Allowing width and height attributes and messing with that sort function have basically solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The following (almost) fixed my two issues:

1. Allowing width and height attributes on the image solved the issue of rewriting to style attribute. In config, I used the (oddly named, as I am 'allowing', not 'disallowing': `config.disallowedContent = 'img{width,height}';`.
2. Disabling the sort function (as detailed in my question) fixed most of the ordering problem, except the alt attribute stubbornly stays put after width and height.